# how to destroy view object that i created earlier

Tags: android, android-view

I want to destroy object **popupView** object of `View` class i created in `OnClickListener`.

I want the mechanism such that every time it should create new `View`. I am having problem with the way I am creating `View` object.

My full code:

```
package com.addictioncounterapp;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddictionDetails extends Activity 
{
TextView tv_addiction_name, tv_today, tv_yesterday, tv_this_week, tv_this_month, tv_total;
ImageView iv_back, iv_filter;
int year, month, day;
int placeData;
Boolean state = false;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;
SQLiteDatabase database;
int cat_id = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addiction_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String cat_name = intent.getStringExtra("cat_name");
    tv_addiction_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddictionDetails);
    tv_addiction_name.setText(cat_name);

    tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_total);
    tv_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_today);
    tv_yesterday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_yesterday);
    tv_this_week = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_this_week);
    tv_this_month = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_this_month);

    iv_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAddictionDetailsBack);
    iv_back.setClickable(true);
    iv_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                        {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(AddictionDetails.this, StartActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                );

    iv_filter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAddictionDetailsFilter);
    iv_filter.setClickable(true);
    iv_filter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                        {   
                                            if(state == false)
                                            {
                                                state = true;
                                                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                                final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter_addiction_form, null);

                                                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                                popupWindow.setWidth(300);
                                                popupWindow.setHeight(300);

                                                final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                                year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                                month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                                day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                                                final EditText etStartDate = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.editTextFilterStartDate);
                                                etStartDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                                                                    {   
                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            showDialog(1);
                                                                                            placeData = 1;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                );

                                                final EditText etEndDate = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.editTextFilterEndDate);
                                                etEndDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                                                                    {   
                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            showDialog(1);
                                                                                            placeData = 2;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                            );

                                                Button btn_done = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
                                                btn_done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                                                            {
                                                                                 @Override
                                                                                 public void onClick(View v)
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     if(etStartDate.getText()+""=="" || etEndDate.getText()+""=="")
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(AddictionDetails.this);
                                                                                         adb.setTitle("Error");
                                                                                         adb.setMessage("Fields can't be blank.");
                                                                                         adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                                                                         adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                                                                                         {
                                                                                                                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                                                                                                             {
                                                                                                                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                                                                                                             }
                                                                                                                         }
                                                                                                                );
                                                                                         AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
                                                                                         ad.show();
                                                                                     }
                                                                                     else
                                                                                     {
                                                                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                                                                                        Date date1 = null;
                                                                                        try
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            date1 = sdf.parse(etStartDate.getText()+"");
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        catch (ParseException e)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                                                        }

                                                                                        Date date2 = null;
                                                                                        try
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            date2 = sdf.parse(etEndDate.getText()+"");
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        catch (ParseException e)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                                                        }

                                                                                        System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
                                                                                        System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

                                                                                        if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(AddictionDetails.this);
                                                                                            adb.setTitle("Error");
                                                                                            adb.setMessage("Start date cannot be greater than End date.");
                                                                                            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                                                                            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                                                                                         {
                                                                                                                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                                                     dialog.dismiss();
                                                                                                                                 }
                                                                                                                             }
                                                                                                                    );
                                                                                             AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
                                                                                             ad.show();
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        else
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(AddictionDetails.this, FilteredData.class);
                                                                                            intent.putExtra("start_date", etStartDate.getText()+"");
                                                                                            intent.putExtra("end_date", etEndDate.getText()+"");
                                                                                            intent.putExtra("cat_id", cat_id);
                                                                                            intent.putExtra("cat_name", cat_name);
                                                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                     } 
                                                                                 }
                                                                             }
                                                                        );

                                                Button btn_cancel = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
                                                btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                                                                {
                                                                                     @Override
                                                                                     public void onClick(View v)
                                                                                     {

                                                                                         popupWindow.dismiss();

                                                                                         state = false;
                                                                                     }
                                                                                 }
                                                                            );

                                                dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                                                                    {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                                                                        {
                                                                            SimpleDateFormat tmpDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                                                            Calendar tmpC1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                                                            tmpC1.set(yr, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                                                                            Date tmpD1 = tmpC1.getTime();
                                                                            String tmpDateString = tmpDateFormat.format(tmpD1);                                                                             
                                                                            update(placeData, tmpDateString);
                                                                        }

                                                                        private void update(int position, String strDate)
                                                                        {
                                                                            switch(position)
                                                                            {
                                                                                case 1:
                                                                                    Log.e("In Addiction details In startDate", strDate);

                                                                                    etStartDate.setText(strDate);
                                                                                    break;

                                                                                case 2:
                                                                                    Log.e("In Addiction details In endDate", strDate);

                                                                                    etEndDate.setText(strDate);
                                                                                    break;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    };

                                                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(iv_filter, 0, 0);
                                            }                                               
                                        }
                                    }
                                );

    loadDB();

    Cursor cursor = database.query("category", new String[]{"cat_id"}, "cat_name=?", new String[]{cat_name}, null, null, null);

    //----------------------fetching id-------------------

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
            cat_id = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();

    //----------------------fetching total-------------------

    int totalCounter;
    Cursor totalCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+";", null);
    if(totalCursor.moveToNext())
        totalCounter = totalCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        totalCounter = 0;
    totalCursor.close();
    tv_total.setText(totalCounter+"");

    //----------------------fetching today's count---------------

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    String todays_date = dateFormat1.format(cal1.getTime());
    int todayCounter;

    Cursor todayCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date = '"+todays_date+"';", null);
    if(todayCursor.moveToNext())
        todayCounter = todayCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        todayCounter = 0;
    todayCursor.close();

    tv_today.setText(todayCounter+"");

    //----------------------fetching yesterdays count------------------

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    String yesterdays_date = dateFormat2.format(cal2.getTime());

    int yesterdayCounter = 0;

    Cursor yesterdayCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date = '"+yesterdays_date+"';", null);

    if(yesterdayCursor.moveToFirst())
        yesterdayCounter = yesterdayCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        yesterdayCounter = 0;

    yesterdayCursor.close();

    tv_yesterday.setText(yesterdayCounter+"");

    //-------------------------fetching current week count--------------------

    SimpleDateFormat weekDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    Date weekFirstDate = c1.getTime();
    String strWeekFirstDay = weekDateFormat.format(weekFirstDate);

    Cursor weekCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date BETWEEN '"+strWeekFirstDay+"' AND '"+todays_date+"';", null);

    int weekCounter = 0;
    if(weekCursor.moveToFirst())
        weekCounter = weekCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        weekCounter = 0;
    weekCursor.close();

    tv_this_week.setText(weekCounter+"");

    //----------------------fetching current month count--------------------

    SimpleDateFormat monthDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date monthFirstDate = c2.getTime();
    String strMonthFirstDay = monthDateFormat.format(monthFirstDate);

    Cursor monthCursor = database.rawQuery("select sum(cat_attribute_unit) from counter where cat_id ="+cat_id+" AND counter_entry_date BETWEEN '"+strMonthFirstDay+"' AND '"+todays_date+"';", null);
    int monthCounter = 0;
    if(monthCursor.moveToFirst())
        monthCounter = monthCursor.getInt(0);
    else
        monthCounter = 0;
    monthCursor.close();

    tv_this_month.setText(monthCounter+"");

    database.close();
}

private void loadDB() 
{
    database = openOrCreateDatabase("AddictionCounter.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);
}
}
```

Also i am not able to refer any class inside my IF Loop of `OnClickListener`. It gives an error while giving **Ctrl+space**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

destroy popupView at

```
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener
```

Answer (score 1):

First attempt to answer, correct me if I have to re-read.

I think the normal practice is to create a member popupWindow and then use setContentView and dismiss to show it or not show it.  But if you really need to destroy it and create it each time onClick goes:

- Don't declare it as final. GC will clean it normally between calls to onClick
- call dismiss() once the changes are done

What do you mean you can't refer any class inside the listener? Do you mean you can't call things like onPause()  methods? Just in case, consider that when you do this.SOMETHING inside the listener, you are not doing it from an Activity anymore. If you need to refer to onCreateDialog or something you can do it by getParent

Comment: In my case, i am having class the class AddictionDetails. okay...  in that IF loop, if i write Addic **Ctrl+Space** it shows me error in the bottom of eclipse window. What could be the reason that i am not able to find any class hitting **Ctrl+space** in that particular IF loop...

Comment: Hmm you should be able. Could it that eclipse is not getting the template? Try just using the full qualified name com.addictioncounterapp.AddictionDetails and check for compile errors. Also, if what you want is to access any of its members you should be able to reference them directly. Does that work?

Comment: Okay, i'll try for it. Thank you, big bro, for your suggestion.